# Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT

Tags: ios, swift, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

Integrated Jitsi Meet SDK with latest version on iOS

It's working with two three time then crashed app with below error

Getting crashed with Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Start a one-to-one call with a person.
- After the receiver person joins, they leave the meeting.
- Start another one-to-one call.
- After the receiver person joins again, they leave the meeting.
- As a result, the iOS app crashes, and we are receiving the following error:

  ```
  Thread running at QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE waiting on a lower QoS thread running at QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT. Investigate ways to avoid priority inversions.”
  ```

Here is the log information:

```
2023-05-25 12:40:13.351655+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032673] [JitsiMeetSDK] [JitsiConference.js] Removing remote P2P track: RemoteTrack[userID: f9dd57e1, type: audio, ssrc: 2609474008, p2p: true, sourceName: f9dd57e1-a0, status: {readyState: live, muted: false, enabled: true}] 
2023-05-25 12:40:13.351803+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032662] [JitsiMeetSDK] [JitsiConference.js] Stopping remote stats for P2P connection participantLeft [AnyHashable(“participantId”): f9dd57e1] 
2023-05-25 12:40:13.354828+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032872] [JitsiMeetSDK] [JitsiConference.js] Stopping CallStats for P2P connection 
2023-05-25 12:40:13.355889+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032674] [JitsiMeetSDK] [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] JingleSessionPC[session=P2P,initiator=true,sid=07968ae8bcb6] Skipped sending session-terminate 
2023-05-25 12:40:13.357528+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032662] [JitsiMeetSDK] [modules/xmpp/JingleSessionPC.js] JingleSessionPC[session=P2P,initiator=true,sid=07968ae8bcb6] Session terminated undefined undefined 
2023-05-25 12:40:13.361885+0530 GatherHall-Staging[14842:1032662] [JitsiMeetSDK] [JitsiConference.js] Peer to peer connection closed!
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any assistance with the above problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not used Jitsi myself, but it sounds like if it works two three times and then crash (also the error message itself) that you might have a time race-condition where you should use the GCD yourself to get back on main thread?